# Group data based on the ID with grouped data in comma separated new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like below.

[image]

i need a VBA code to get the result like below:

[image]

basically, I need to check for each ID, what are the impacted app and manager involved and get this together into a single row.

1   WTA    abc

1   TRS    abc

1   STS    rinu

the above needs to be assembled in the new worksheet as a single row like below

1   WTA,TRS,STS    abc,rinu

Appreciate any help as i am not able to move forward.

**Table**

| Req ID. | Impacted App | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WTA | abc |
| 1 | TRS | abs |
| 1 | STS | rinu |
| 2 | STR | arun |
| 2 | PGP | mari |
| 2 | TRS | nom |
| 3 | TBR | ran |
| 3 | ABC | ran |

Result Table:

| Req ID. | Impacted App | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WTA, TRS, STS | abc, rinu |
| 2 | STR, PGP, TRS | arun, mari, nom |
| 3 | TBR, ABC | ran |

---

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: currently i am using a formula to check if id in A2 = id in A3 , if so, add the impacted app in B2 to B3. same in manager as well. i am triying to automate this but i am not sure how to

Comment: =IF((A2=A3),B2&","&B3). And i copied this same for entire rows. The actual data is almost 10K records with many similar records

Comment: The picture is the source or the result of the data. How is the other?

Comment: added the source now, for unique id, i need to concatenate all the impacted app and manager

Answer (score 2):

Put input data in Columns A,B,C on sheet1, output is to Sheet2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub groupdata()

    Dim dictID As Object, dictApp As Object, dictMng As Object
    Dim id As String, app As String, mng As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, k
   
    Set dictID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' input
    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            id = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            app = Trim(.Cells(r, "B"))
            mng = Trim(.Cells(r, "C"))
            
            If Not dictID.exists(id) Then
                Set dictApp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                Set dictMng = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                dictID.Add id, Array(dictApp, dictMng)
            End If
           
            dictID(id)(0)(app) = 1
            dictID(id)(1)(mng) = 1
        Next
    End With

    ' output
    r = 1
    With Sheet2
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        .Range("A1:C1") = Array("req id", "impacted app", "manager")
        For Each k In dictID
            r = r + 1
            .Cells(r, "A") = k
            .Cells(r, "B") = Join(dictID(k)(0).keys, ",")
            .Cells(r, "C") = Join(dictID(k)(1).keys, ",")
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox r - 1 & " rows output to " & Sheet2.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: @doubting Try updated code

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac).

In Power Query, it is a single function (`Table.Group`) to combine duplicate ID's and output a string of the unique apps and managers.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`.
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"req id", Int64.Type}, {"impacted app", type text}, {"manager", type text}
        }),

//Group by ID, then combine the impacted app and manager columns (after removing duplicates
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"req id"}, {
        {"impacted app", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([impacted app]),","), type text},
        {"manager", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([manager]),","), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a slightly simplified version of @CDP1802 's code

```
Option Explicit    

Sub GroupData2()

    Dim IDToAppDict As Scripting.Dictionary, _
        IDToMgrDict As Scripting.Dictionary
   
        Set IDToAppDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set IDToMgrDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

        ' input
        With Sheet1
            Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                If IDToAppDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
                    IDToAppDict(cel.Value) = IDToAppDict(cel.Value) & "," & WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Offset(, 1).Value)
                    IDToMgrDict(cel.Value) = IDToMgrDict(cel.Value) & "," & WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Offset(, 2).Value)
                Else
                    IDToAppDict(cel.Value) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Offset(, 1).Value)
                    IDToMgrDict(cel.Value) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Offset(, 2).Value)
                End If
            Next
        End With
    
        ' output
        With Sheet2
            .UsedRange.ClearContents
            .Range("A1:C1") = Array("req id", "impacted app", "manager")
            .Range("A2").Resize(IDToAppDict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(IDToAppDict.Keys)
            .Range("B2").Resize(IDToAppDict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(IDToAppDict.Items)
            .Range("C2").Resize(IDToAppDict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(IDToMgrDict.Items)
            .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With

End Sub
```

it requires to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library (in VBA IDE: Tools->References)